# Using jQuery to find the content of a <td>

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am trying to use jQuery to find `<td>`s with given content (text) inside. For example:

http://sotkra.com/btol/index.php

From left to right, the 7th COLUMN that reads 'TIPO MONEDA' displays either PESOS or DOLARES. I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. Select `<td>`s with the text 'DOLARES' or 'PESOS' and add a class to them.
2. Select `<td>`s with the text 'DOLARES' or 'PESOS' and add a class to their parent `<tr>`s.

For #1, I tried with this:

```
$('td[innerHTML=Dolares]').addClass('highlight');
```

and also

```
$('td[html=Dolares]').addClass('highlight');
```

Neither of which worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use [`:contains`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text).

```
$('td:contains("Dolares")').addClass('highlight');
```

for the parent

```
$('td:contains("Dolares")').parent().addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: @Sotkra: Do note `contains` looks for text (not html) and is case sensitive :)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the linked documentation.  If you need to differentiate various table elements that might contain the same string or need case insensitivity you could use filter() and supply a function that does a regex match on the text() of each element.

Comment: Thanks for that tvan. Now, I was wondering how you'd do the opposite of the above, meaning, exclude (hide or hightlight, doesn't matter) rows which have a td with a value of X. As for the suggested filter(), I don't know how to do what you suggested. A suggestion by a friend, which works with case SENSITIVITY goes as follows: $('td').filter(function(){return $(this).html() == 'Dolares'}).parent('tr').addClass('highlight'); How would you transform it into case insensitive?

Comment: return $(this).text().match( /^\s*dolares\s*$/i ) != null;  would do nicely to match only *dolares* in a case insensitive way.  Use the hide()/show() function on the parent example to hide/show the row containing the string.

Comment: What about the inverse though?

"Thanks for that tvan. Now, I was wondering how you'd do the opposite of the above, meaning, exclude (hide or hightlight, doesn't matter) rows which have a td with a value of X."

Comment: $('td:not:contains("Dolares")')  or simply reverse the sense of the comparison in the function.

Comment: Yeah, silly me. I did that and it worked. It's nice to see you can also use :not:contains too. Thanks a lot TVAN.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [jQuery selector reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors), I don't think
`$('td[innerHTML=Dolares]')` and
`$('td[html=Dolares]')` is going to work.

I can only think of iterating through all the TDs and check the `$(tdselector).html()` content.

You can try `contains("Dolares")` as suggested by tvanfosson though. It works for your case as it's highly unlikely you will have "xxDolaresxx" in other TDs.

Answer (score -1):

You're very close, just missing some ticks around the value in your selector. This should work:

```
$("td[innerHTML='Dolares']").addClass('highlight');
```

And, for the parent selector:

```
$("td[innerHTML='Dolares'][innerHTML='Pesos']").parent().addClass('someClass');
```